# Spring form th:object and th:field

Tags: java, spring-boot, spring-mvc, thymeleaf

I would like to capture just the input name to the spieler object.

```
<form th:action="@{/login}" method="post" th:object="${spieler}">
     <label for="nameInput" class="mt-4">Tragen einfach deinen Name ein, um deine Reise zu beginnen :</label>
     <br>
     <div class="d-flex justify-content-center my-4" >
          <input type="text" class="form-control" id="nameInput" th:field="*{name}">
          <button type="submit" class="btn-secondary ">Beginnen</button>
     </div>
</form>
```

this is the controller

```
@PostMapping("/login")
public String login (@ModelAttribute("spieler") Spieler spieler){
    spielerRepository.save(spieler);
    return "redirect:/";
}
```

and the Spieler-class:

```
@Data
public class Spieler {
     private int id;
     private String name;
     private int level;
     private int punkte;

     public Spieler (String name){
        this.name = name;
        this.level = 1;
        this.punkte = 0;
     }
}
```

the thymeleaf don't do that. How can i please solve this problem ?
Sorry for bad English !

Answer (score 1):

It will be easier to create a dedicated object for the form parameters. For instance, you could create a class `LoginFormData`:

```
public class LoginFormData {
  private String name;

  // getters and setters here
}
```

Update your controller to use it:

```
@GetMapping("/login")
public String showLogin(Model model) {
  model.addAttribute("spieler", new LoginFormData());
  return "login"; // assuming your template is called `login.html`
}

@PostMapping("/login")
public String login (@ModelAttribute("spieler") LoginFormData formData){
    Spieler spieler = new Spieler(formData.getName());
    spielerRepository.save(spieler);
    return "redirect:/";
}
```

You can of course also use `loginFormData` as model attribute name, but then you need to update the HTML as well.

See [Form handling with Thymeleaf](https://www.wimdeblauwe.com/blog/2021/05/23/form-handling-with-thymeleaf/) for more details on this.

Comment: Please accept the answer using the check mark so other know that your question was answered. Thanks!